# Validar dato en un dto Spring Boot

Tags: java, regex, spring-boot

Tengo un dto utilizado para recibir datos de un objeto y en el cual valido un dato mediante una expresión regular de la siguiente forma:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "[A-Za-z0-9 ]+")
```

Necesitaría agregar para el atributo que además de aceptar letras mayúsculas, minúsculas y espacios, también acepte el caracter especial "/"

Cómo puedo agregarlo a la expresión regular?

Gracias!!!

Answer (score 1):

Era tan simple como agregar la barra dentro de la expresión regular:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "[A-Za-z0-9 /]+")
```